# SQLiteOpenHelper interface, access override methods 'onCreate'

Tags: android

```
public void onSave(View v){  // this is the activity which calls sqllite 
     Connectivity cn = new Connectivity(getApplicationContext());
     SQLiteDatabase sqlDb = cn.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

In my sqllite open helper class where my database operation is performed
  in the following code, I can't  access the "OnCreate" or "OnUpdate" method, and any how my application is working quite good without any exception or error

```
public class Connectivity extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
final static String db_name="Attendence";
SQLiteDatabase sqlDb;
Context cn = null;
Connectivity(Context context){
    super(context,db_name , null, 1);
    cn = context;
    toast.message(cn, "constructor called");

}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
    db.execSQL("create table class_ref(id number primarykey autoincrement," +
            "class_name varchar(20),no_students int,reg_no text");
    }catch(Exception e){
        toast.message(cn, "EXCEPTION:"+e.toString());
    }
    toast.message(cn, "onCreate method called");    
}
```

I am not getting either one of the toast messages declared above

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
        toast.message(cn, "onupgrade called");
        db.execSQL("drop table class_ref if exists");
        onCreate(db);
    }catch(Exception e){
        toast.message(cn, "EXCEPTION:"+e.toString());
    }toast.message(cn, "on update method called");  
}
```

}

Output :

```
toast message 'constructor called '
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lifecycle methods of an Android SQLite database are only called when the version code sent to the constructor changes.

When debugging, instead of setting a constant, try changing the version dynamically to trigger the lifecycle methods.

```
Connectivity(Context context, int version){
    super(context,db_name , null, version);
    cn = context;
    toast.message(cn, "constructor called");
}
```